# Is this correct for non-inverting op-amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, low-pass

[image: op-amp sheme]

Do 0.1 uf and 100 k ohm act as low-pass filter in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do 0.1 uf and 100 k ohm act as low-pass filter in here?

No, since there is no current through the parallel RC network, there is zero volts across the network and so

$$V_{out} = V_- = V_+ = V_{in}$$

thus, the circuit implements a unity gain buffer:

$$V_{out} = V_{in} $$

Another way to see this is to consider the canonical non-inverting configuration in the frequency domain:

[image]

The transfer function (frequency response) is:

$$\dfrac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} = 1 + \dfrac{Z_2}{Z_1} $$

In the schematic you provide, \$Z_1\$ is an open circuit, i.e. \$Z_1 = \infty \$.  Thus, the transfer function for your circuit is:

$$\dfrac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} = 1 + \dfrac{Z_2}{\infty} = 1$$

which is, as before, just a unity gain buffer. Now, if you place a resistor \$R_1\$ to ground from the inverting input, the transfer function is:

$$\dfrac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} = 1 + \dfrac{100k\Omega || \frac{1}{j \omega (0.1\mu F)}}{R_1}$$

which will provide some filtering - the details of which I will leave as an exercise for the reader.

:)

Comment: what 100 ohm resistors do in front of Vin+ and behind Vout ?

Comment: For an ideal op-amp, the resistor in series with Vin+ is irrelevant since there is no current into the Vin+ terminal.  The resistor in series with Vout simply increases the output resistance of the circuit from 0 to 100 Ohms.

Comment: what if connect 4.7 m resistor to Vin+ net and ground this net with 2.2 nf cap. ? im asking because i see someone use this.

Comment: @user30878, it's not clear how you want the resistor and capacitor connected.  Draw a schematic or give a more complete description.

Answer (score 2):

Without an impedance from Vin- to ground this is a unity gain amplifier with no intentional frequency shaping. The 100k passes the output to Vin- and because it isn't attenuated - this circuit IS a unity gain amplifier. No amount of shunting the 100k with the 100nF capacitor is going to make a difference.

**EDIT to show a 2nd order Sallen Key Low pass filter**
If you need a decent non-inverting filter I can recommend the unity gain sallen key filter and in particular [this](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPstool.php) site. Here's the values I plugged-in for a 15Hz low pass filter: -

[image]

For single supply operation the values are still good except you need to create a mid rail point that is suitable for your signal to be referenced to. It's probably a good idea to use another op-amp set as a unity gain non-inverting configuration with a resistor to Vsupply + and a resistor to Vsupply -. This forms a potential divider that creates your 0V midrail supply. If you look at [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa163/sloa163.pdf) document page 9 onwards has also got some decent ideas about creating a split power rail.

You can also look at [this](http://www.talkingelectronics.com/projects/OP-AMP/OP-AMP-2.html) site for ideas - look for "THE OP-AMP AS A VOLTAGE FOLLOWER" - feed the junction of the two resistors (mentioned above) onto the input and you get a steady output that equals half rail.

If you need confirmation of what the circuit looks like [here](http://www.eng.yale.edu/ee-labs/morse/compo/sloa058.pdf) is another reference in figure 2. Good luck.

Comment: So then how can a low-pass filter be applied to the signal -while unity gain remains- on the Vin- to Vout connection line? And what 100 ohm resistors do before Vin+ and after Vout?

Comment: http://www.66pacific.com/ph/ph_4.htm there are "r 352" and "c 350" a resistor and a capacitor, connected just as image i gave above, and page says its low pass filter?

Comment: Unfortunately you need gain so that this can be reduced by the appropriate components. Unity gain is rock bottom. Different configurations might work for you. Try lookin up unity gain Sallen-Key

Comment: That is not unity gain. Btw your original question didn't call for unity gain.

Comment: i will use unity-gain. and http://www.ewubd.edu/~iraza/sallen-key.pdf do sallen-key always should be use with inverting mode? or circuits given in the pdf are non-inverting ?

Comment: Sallen key is non inverting. Do you want me to leave a proper answer.

Comment: Yes please.  I need unity gain configured buffer and 15 hz input filtering. I also use single supply so i need some offset.

Comment: @user30878 sallen key added to my answer.

Comment: If \$R=R_1=R_2\$ and \$C=C_1=C_2\$ \$f_o=\dfrac{1}{2\pi RC}\$.

Comment: @Matt for unity gain with Rs and Cs equal you'll get a weak filter without maximizing bandwidth. Butterworth is best because this   is maximally flat.