# Tactics for stable unity-gain op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, meter, ph, stable

The circuit given below is typical pH meter op-amp circuit. But here LMC6001 is not configured as unity gain.

[image: typical ph meter circuit]

My question is this, I want to make this circuit with unity-gain buffer op-amp. What about R2, R4, C1 and R9 in here? What do they do? Are they useful to make signal stable?

What about making LMC6001 unity-gain by removing R1,R2,R3 and moving C1 R9 shunt to LMC6001's feedback loop?

And what I understand yet: R1, R3 are gain resistors. LMC6041's function is adding reference voltage (adjusted by R8 // R6,R7,R8 resistor divider) offset to ADC's input (or pH signal).

Comment: Why do you want to make it unity-gain? You do know that the nominal ph-probe output is ~0.06V/ph, right? You're going to need gain *somewhere*.

Comment: Nope. I have got enough offset voltage. No gain is needed. Plus, i don't use negative rail (single supply).

Comment: You're missing the point. What device are you using that can resolve well *below* 60 millivolts? Because right now, 60 millivolts change equates to a difference of 1 pH. Unless you need only the coarsest of coarse measurements, a plain MCU ADC probably won't work too well here.

Comment: You know there are a lot of ADCs up to 12 bit resolution.

Comment: I know there are ADCs with *24* bit resolution (or higher!), but no matter what the bit size of your ADC, only using part of it's input range is poor engineering.

Comment: Its true but for now i don't work on a commercial product, just prototyping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to think of this circuit in two sections. Everything before R4 belongs in the first section. R4, and everything after it, belongs in the second section. Now the first section looks like a standard op-amp noninverting voltage amplifier. As you probably know, the gain of such an amplifier is equal to \$1 + Z_f/Z_{in}\$, where \$Z_f\$ is the feedback impedance and \$Z_{in}\$ is the input impedance. The second section is an inverting voltage amplifier, with gain equal to \$-Z_f/Z_{in}\$.

The gain of the first section (with the LMC6001 op-amp) is therefore equal to 1 + (R2+R_V)/R1, where R_V is the variable resistance setting of the R3 potentiometer. The simplest way to change this to a unity-gain buffer is actually just to remove R1 and short the V- terminal to the output. The op-amp forces V- to equal V+, so if V- is shorted to the output, then the output must also equal V+.

The gain of the second section is -R9/R4 = -1. You correctly observe that the network connected to the positive input of the LMC6041 is supposed to add a DC offset. So this section is already at unity gain, but it's inverting.

The capacitor C1, in combination with R9, acts as a low-pass filter with a cutoff frequency of 0.7 Hz. That makes sure that the output voltage changes slowly, so you can read the output with a multimeter.

Comment: Thanks for very clear answer. Three questions now: 1- Why don't remove R1,R2,R3 instead of making them equal? 2- What kind of low pass filtering is this? Its not look like active or passive low pass filters that i learn. What it filters? Is it filtering reference offset voltage or pH signal? 3- With unity gain configuration, just seen in here http://i.stack.imgur.com/iZzJl.png adding same valued serial resistor both before Vin and feedback loop is useful for making signal stable?

Comment: Q1. The whole point of an op-amp is that it has a huge intrinsic voltage gain - generally over 10^6. This gain is "tamed" by the feedback network. If you simply remove the feedback, though, you won't get unity gain. You'll get 10^6*(V+ - V-) where V+ and V- are the voltages at the input pins. Excellent explanations of op-amp basics can be found in The Art of Electronics by Horowitz and Hill (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Electronics).

Comment: Q2. The voltage gain is the feedback *impedance* divided by the input *impedance*. The capacitor impedance is equal to 1/(2 pi j f C) where f is the frequency. So the capacitor shorts out the high frequencies.

Comment: "you won't get unity gain. You'll get 10^6*(V+ - V-).." ok but V- is 0 in my circuit, its grounded.

Comment: Q3. Adding a series resistor to the output of an op-amp can sometimes make the circuit more stable when high-frequency oscillations are a problem. It can also be useful to avoid overdriving the current of the output stage. In your application, I don't think either of these is a concern.

Comment: further to Q1: there are always voltage and current offsets at the input pins of an op-amp. These can be several mV. Also, the op-amp output could easily push current through R1. In that case, V- certainly won't be at ground anymore.

Comment: @Dave : note the pH probe connects to +ve input, so the first stage gain is about +1.7, not -0.7.

Comment: Will these several mV be go away with unity-gain resistors? Voltage offsets are not disturb my application if they are stable always. I just don't want noise voltages.

Comment: @BrianDrummond: You're quite right, I was too speedy. And it changes the answer quite a lot. I've fixed my answer.

Comment: @user30878: The offset voltage is a property of the op-amp, so there is no way to make it go away. The good news is that the offset voltage is probably much larger than the noise voltage in your application. Op-amp data sheets will specify both the offset voltage and the noise voltage.

Comment: @DaveKielpinski so i don't need to use feedback resistors :)

Comment: @user30878: Not if you just want unity gain on the first stage, no. But you do need to short V- to the output! Sorry about my confusion before. Usually V+ is above V- in the schematic, but in this one it's the other way around. I just didn't look carefully enough.

Comment: The (DC) gain of the second stage is -R9/R4 = -1.  (Depending on the input the OP may need the negative supply rail.)

Comment: @Dave : now the second stage description is wrong - was correct before!

Comment: @GeorgeHerold: Thanks. Guess I should not try to answer questions late at night. Fixed...

Comment: @user30878: Comments pointed out that, in fixing my mistake last night, I introduced another mistake. This has now been corrected.

Comment: @DaveKielpinski Hi, i read your answer again. Please look here http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/86494/is-this-correct-for-non-inverting-op-amp they say paralleled 100k res. and 0.1 uF cap. won't act as filter here.

Comment: @user30878 Your link talks about noninverting op-amps, but the second section is inverting. The key point in the link is that there is no current flow through the feedback network. However, there is clearly current flow in your case.